# get most frecuent k-length kmers in string

Tags: c#

Supposing I have a string like `"01xTTx10TxT1x10Tx0Tx10Tx0x0x1T"` I would like to gen all 4 kmers of that string

```
01xT Tx10 TxT1 x10T x0Tx 10Tx 0x0x 1T
1xTT x10T xT1x 10Tx 0Tx1 0Tx0 x0x1 T
xTTx 10Tx T1x1 0Tx0 Tx10 Tx0x 0x1T
...
```

And then, having them all, know which are most frecuent.

To do so I am planning to do create a dictionary and the based on appereance increment a count like:

```
string original = "01xTTx10TxT1x10Tx0Tx10Tx0x0x1T";
int size = 4;
string[] arr = "" ;  // how to gen kmers(original,4); ?

Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string word in arr) //loop over all kmers
{
   if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word)) //if it's in the dictionary
       dictionary[word] = dictionary[word] + 1; //Increment the count
   else
       dictionary[word] = 1; //put it in the dictionary with a count 1
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in dictionary) //loop through the dictionary
     System.Console.Write(string.Format("{0} {1} \n", pair.Key, pair.Value));
```

but I am not sure how to gen efficiently all 4-size kemrs from string

so in the example I should get that most frecuent kmers are

```
10Tx 
x10T
```

which are most frecuent words in original string 
`01xTTx` **10Tx** `T1x` **10Tx** `0Tx` **10Tx** `0x0x1T`
and
  `01xTT` **x10T** `xT1` **x10T** `x0T` **x10T** `x0x0x1T`

Or what would be a better approach to know the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a loop to get all kmers, and then use regex to find all matches in your input string. The most frequently occurring kmer will win.
Something like this:

```
var term = "01xTTx10TxT1x10Tx0Tx10Tx0x0x1T";
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (var i = 0; i < term.Length - 4; i++)
{
    var kmer = term.Substring(i, 4);
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(kmer))
        dict[kmer] = Regex.Matches(term, kmer).Count;

}

var maxOccurring = dict.Max(m => m.Value);
var maxOccurringTerm = dict.Where(l => l.Value == maxOccurring);
```